# Problem with sequence alignment

Tags: proteins, sequence-alignment, sequence

I'm trying to find if the peptides in column A are present within the longer peptides of column B.

Pairwise alignment tools take the data from both columns as one string (i.e., TIIDYTNNHYTNNHLEII... and PFYMNITGYTDAYNTDIIDYIIDYTNNHLEIITLFN...) which leads to a number of peptides from column A left unaligned even though the peptide is present within one of the longer peptides in column B.

I would like to find a method that works for detecting such peptides.

[image: columns depicted here]

Comment: Easy, few details are you stuck with a CSV format or prepared to copy and paste column A to one file and column B to another. Its solvable either way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you want an *alignment* so much as you want to *test for the presence of an exact substring* (column A) *within larger strings* (column B).

There are simple excel utilities that do this, for example the `SEARCH()` [function](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text). There is no need to use alignments.